# Как сделать вывод данных из базы данных в лист?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица `users`, в ней есть столбцы `id`, `user_id`, `card_a`, `card_b`, `card_c`, `card_d`. Если карточка есть у пользователя в боте, то в строке пользователя указывается 1, если нет, то 0. Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию в меню кнопки `Мои карты` - ему выводились карточки которые есть в наличии, но чтобы это было все в меню, то есть открывается первая карточка которая у него есть, например `card_b`, дальше нажав стрелочку у него откроется другая карточка, например `card_c` и аналогично например карточка `card_d`. Не могу понять как выводить в лист те карточки, которые есть у пользователя в наличии. Пытался сделать это все через обычную проверку, но остановился на этапе начала самой проверки, не понял как сделать проверку данных в наличии, база данных у меня [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3), пишу на языке [python](/questions/tagged/python) через библиотеку [telebot](/questions/tagged/telebot). Я так понимаю, что делается это через `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример простого кода

```
id_=123                    #вставьте сюда команду для получения ID
a=b=c=d=False
dict_={0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d'}
for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT card_a,card_b,card_c,card_d FROM users where user_id={id_}"):
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i]==1:
            eval(f'{dict[i]}=True')
list_=[i for i in ('a','b','c','d') if eval(i)]
```

В массиве `list_` хранятся *строковые* названия переменных (карточек), которые есть у пользователя.

Comment: а можно как то указать какой первый, какой последний?

Comment: Кто первый? Кто последний?